# How to calculate this integral?

Tags: integration, markov-chains

I got confused with this Markov Chain problem:

suppose the kernel $Q$ is $Q_x=N(cx,1)$, $c$ is a fixed constant with $|c|<1$ and the stationary distribution is $\pi=N(0,\frac{1}{1-c^2})$.

I want to verify the stationary distribution, so I have
$$\pi Q = \int_{x \in \mathbb{R} } Q_x \, d\pi(x) $$

The problem is, how to evaluate that integral with respect to the measure $\pi(x)$? In other words, how to figure out this integral?

Thank you.

Comment: Actually $\pi=N(0,1/(1-c^2))$. To show this, assume that $X\sim N(0,a^2)$ and show that $N(cX,1)$ is $N(0,c^2a^2+1)$. Hence...

Comment: @Did How to calculate the integral? I don't know what to do with that $d\pi(x)$...

Comment: Did you read my comment?

Comment: @Did I did, and was wondering why we assume $X~N(0,a^2)$? Though I understand the rest: set $c^2 a^2 +1 = a^2$ and get $a^2 = 1/(1-c^2)$ and $\pi = N(0, 1/(1-c^2))$. My only confusion is with that assumption.

Comment: Sorry? This shows that the centered normal distribution with a well chosen variance is stationary, no?

Comment: @Did Gotcha. That makes sense

Comment: Do not deface your own question once you got an answer.  That's rude and it is against site guidelines.

Comment: What @heropup said. The right thing to do is to write down a solution yourself, to post it as an answer and even, after a while, possibly to accept it.